High gas and transaction cost
so this has worked before but now I seem to be getting insufficent funds when I try to create a lock
but what I dont understand is why it's expecting so much gas and transaction fee (165 Matic)
if I don't set a gasPrice/maxFeePergas then it'll say the transaction replacement fee is too low, but once I set a (which I believe is reasonable) gas price it states I don't have enough matic to cover 550000000 supplied gas - wanted to ask if there were any suggestions on how to debug this


